# JSON object to array with JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have the following JSON object

**Input:**

```json
{
  "17.39.108.85:80": [],
  "10.204.32.9:443": [
    {
      "status": "DOWN"
    }
  ]
}
```

and trying to transform it into a list/array as below :

**Desired Output:**

```json
[
  {
    "17.39.108.85:80": []
  },
  {
    "10.204.32.9:443": [
      {
        "status": "DOWN"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What's the best way to use Jolt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this spec:

Currently, your input is correct, but you need to put each key into an array.

You can get each key in the object and send it to an array with `[#2]`.

**Note:** `#2` is the index of each key. for example: `17.39.108.85:80` is `0` and `10.204.32.9:443` is `1`.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you mohammadReza and @Barbaros Özhan
This worked beautifully.